# Convert the yearly columns to rows and add a year column in PySpark

Tags: sql, pyspark, data-manipulation

For example:

| ID | SALESYR2019 | SALESYR2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 50 |
| 2 | 20 | 100 |

| ID | SALESYR | SALES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | 10 |
| 2 | 2019 | 20 |
| 1 | 2020 | 50 |
| 2 | 2020 | 100 |

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is unpivot the table, here is how you can do it:

```
data = [{
    "id":1,
    "SALESYR2019":10,
    "SALESYR2020":50
},
{
    "id":2,
    "SALESYR2019":20,
    "SALESYR2020":100
}
]

df = spark.createDataframe(data)
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
unpivotExpr = "stack(2, '2019', SALESYR2019, '2020', SALESYR2020) as (SALESYR,SALES)"
unPivotDF = df.select("id", expr(unpivotExpr))

unPivotDF.show(truncate=False)
unPivotDF.show()
```

Output

```
>>> unPivotDF.show(truncate=False)
+---+-------+-----+
|id |SALESYR|SALES|
+---+-------+-----+
|1  |2019   |10   |
|1  |2020   |50   |
|2  |2019   |20   |
|2  |2020   |100  |
+---+-------+-----+
```